# Labeling in MapInfo using expressions

Tags: labeling, mapinfo

How do I do this?

Columns -    Sitecode       Acres
             271730-001     .75
             271730-002     .50

I'm trying to label objects by multiplying the Acres column by "2.5".
As an example using first row from above:

????(Acres*2.5, ??)  should label as "1.875"

Comment: Thanks Peter. I was trying waaayyyy too hard on this one. I did not think of the obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MapInfo Professional you can easily setup a label expression in stead of a fixed column.

Pick the text Expression from the "Label with" dropdown list.
In the Expression dialog enter your expressions, in this case:

```
ACRES * 2.5
```

[image]

Hit OK to the Expression dialog and now you have specified a label expression.
If you have turned on Autolabel for the layer you should see the result in the map